# Display LinkedIn profile photo and user profile using LinkedIn API

Tags: objective-c, linkedin-api

I want to display the user profile photo and his profile field such as company-name, job title, industry, and location. 
I call ProfilePicCall to retrieve the profile picture.

```
- (void)ProfilePicCall
{
    NSURL *url  = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/picture-url"];
    OAMutableURLRequest *request =
    [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                    consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                       token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                    callback:nil
                           signatureProvider:nil];

    NSLog(@"the request is %@",request);


    [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];

    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(profileApiCallResult:didFinish:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(profileApiCallResult:didFail:)];
}
```

Then to display the photo in image view I use the below code

```
- (void)profileApiCallResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinish:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *profile = [responseBody objectFromJSONString];
    // [responseBody release];

    if ( profile )
    {
        NSLog(@"Profile is %@",profile);

   NSString *picture_url = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"linkedid_Profile_url"];

        NSURL *imageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:picture_url];

        NSData *imagedata = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:imageurl];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imagedata];
        [LinkedInPicture setImage:image];

     }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *profile = [responseBody objectFromJSONString];
        NSLog(@"last path componemt is %@",profile);

    }
    // The next thing we want to do is call the network updates
    [self networkApiCall];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Used" forKey:@"linkedin"];

}
```

But the image not display in the image view. Please help me to display the image, and how to use LinkedIn API

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution for my question, it should change the LinkedIn API call to be:

```
- (void)profileApiCall
{

// NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,industry,picture-url,location:(name),positions:(company:(name),title),specialties,date-of-birth,interests,languages)"];

OAMutableURLRequest *request =
[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                   token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                callback:nil
                       signatureProvider:nil];

NSLog(@"the request is %@",request);


[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];

OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(profileApiCallResult:didFinish:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(profileApiCallResult:didFail:)];


}
```

Thanks.

Comment: i am not getting user profile url i am using same your code.any reason for that ?

Comment: @ Darshan:-- I have use same code its working perfect, try again

Answer (score 1):

I didn't like the approach above,

First I use this library that helps the logging process in with Auth2.0 for LinkedIn https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI

Use it as follows or read the documentation and change the code by yourselves.

the SOLUTION is this request https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=&format=json

```
LIALinkedInApplication *application = [LIALinkedInApplication applicationWithRedirectURL:@"http://www.ancientprogramming.com/liaexample"
                                                                                  clientId:@"clientId"
                                                                              clientSecret:@"clientSecret"
                                                                                     state:@"DCEEFWF45453sdffef424"
                                                                             grantedAccess:@[@"r_fullprofile", @"r_network"]];



LIALinkedInHttpClient *client = [LIALinkedInHttpClient clientForApplication:application presentingViewController:nil];

[client getAuthorizationCode:^(NSString *code) {
    [client getAccessToken:code success:^(NSDictionary *accessTokenData) {
      NSString *accessToken = [accessTokenData objectForKey:@"access_token"];
      //here you already have you access token
      //SOLUTION == https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&format=json
      //make a http request and get the result with an image url

  } cancel:^{
    NSLog(@"Authorization was cancelled by user");
  } failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Authorization failed %@", error);
  }];
}
```

works fine for me

Comment: thanks, you just make solution in comment, that's why people can't find it.
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&format=json